# Integrate Google authentication into website

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, google-authentication

I am tasked with integrating Google authentication into our portal system. This will be used for two purposes:
1.) To be able to fetch and integrate a user's calendar, contacts etc into our system.
2.) To use as an alternative logon method into our portal. 
The portal runs on WLS and uses OID as the authentication method and this should ideally be able to live side by side with the Google authentication scheme (this bit is not my primary concern - it's my colleague's :).

When I started researching the various available authentication methods, however, I became a bit confused about the direction I should take. Google lists OAuth 2.0, 1.0, Hybrid and OpenID as possible authentication mechanisms. In addition the API Doc mentions a Federated login.

To make my confusion even worse, the OAuth 2.0 doc for instance then goes on to talk about client side web-applications, server side web-applications, native applications etc. etc.

I am therefore wondering if anyone here has implemented anything similar to what I'm trying to do and if so, if you are able to share any experiences, tips, help or similar?

(I will be implementing the client-side mechanism using JavaScript)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenID to support multiple types of login, including Google auth.

http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx

Comment: Excellent introduction, thanks! I'm currently juggling a few tasks here, but I will read your post thoroughly as soon as I can.

Comment: this is why SO doesn't isn't for link only posts; now that it's dead, the answer is useless.